# Get records when Running sum reaches target value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, business-intelligence

```
DECLARE @example TABLE(ID INT, Amount float)
INSERT INTO @example VALUES(1,100), (2,500), (3,50), (4,200)

select * from @example

DECLARE @Target Float = 600
```

Now, I need top records `where Sum(Amount) = @Target`, this target may vary.

Can some one please give me a sql query for this.

Comment: You might want to provide an SQL Fiddle, more details on the structure of the items you are looking for the `SUM` of. What have you already tried? I would suggest starting by looking into using something along the lines of `SELECT ... FROM ... GROUP BY ... HAVING`. Maybe start by reading the guide on "how to ask" (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the cumulative sum using a correlated subquery (as well as other methods).  Assuming that the `id` uniquely identifies rows:

```
select e.*
from (select e.*,
             (select sum(amount)
              from @example e2
              where e2.id <= e.id
             ) as cumamount
      from @example e
     ) e
where cumamount = @Target;
```

This looks for the target value exactly.  More commonly, you want something like:

```
where cumamount >= @Target and cumamount - amount < @Target;
```

That is, the first value that meets or exceeds the `@Target` value.